# Ширина балуна в яндексмап

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

В данный момент карта и объекты на ней подгружаются по следующему алгоритму [клац](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_balloon_async)

Как в данном случае изменить ширину балуна? В документации присутствует такой пример `map.openBalloon(new YMaps.GeoPoint(37.64, 55.76), 'Проверка', {hasCloseButton:false, maxWidth:50})` но у меня балуны выводятся на карту по-другому. Пробовал `obj.properties.maxWidth = 250;` ошибок нет но оно не работает

Answer (score 1):

```
objectManager = new ymaps.LoadingObjectManager(url, {   
  // Включаем кластеризацию.
  clusterize: true,
  gridSize: 128,
  clusterIconLayout: PieChartClustererLayout,
  geoObjectHideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
  clusterHideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
  // Устанавливаем режим открытия балуна. 
  // В данном примере балун никогда не будет открываться в режиме панели.
  clusterBalloonPanelMaxMapArea: 0,
  // Устанавливаем размеры макета контента балуна (в пикселях).
  clusterBalloonContentLayoutWidth: 180,
  clusterBalloonContentLayoutHeight: 140,             
  geoObjectBalloonContentLayoutWidth: 180,
  geoObjectBalloonContentLayoutHeight: 120                
});
```

путем гугления нашел следующий вариант